# JSF bootstrap Glyphicons does not show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

In my web app I use bootstrap. 
Glyphicons was working just fine, and without any reason they stopped. Now there is no icons but empty squares.
I checked for font files - they are intact, just to be sure I replaced them with fresh one from version 3.2 - from full version not from customizer.
I checked css options - everything looks fine:

```
src: url(#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}) format('embedded-opentype');
src: url(#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}) format('woff');
src: url(#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}) format('truetype');
src: url(#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}) format('svg');
```

I checked if the bootstrap.css file is loaded - it is.
And now I'm stuck:

there is no error in chrome or firefox console

fonts are in right place, correctly configured in css file

it's newest version of the fonts

I'm lost - anyone has any idea what to check next?

**EDIT**
my configuration is Wildfly 8.1 final, plus JSF 2.2, bootstrap 3.0 and that's it.

**EDIT 2**
as my coworker just informed me, this issue was first noticed after moving our app to Wildfly 8.0 from Jboss 7.2 so it might be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Add the fonts to `/webapp/resources/fonts` then edit the LESS or CSS that you are using, change the @font-face block to match the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");
    src: url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
            url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'),
            url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
            url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}#glyphicons-halflingsregular") format('svg');
}
```

see my post here: http://www.samael.me.uk/2014/02/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-in-your-java-web.html

edit:
I recommend using LESS over the compiled CSS, it's a lot easier to work with and you can change the entire look easily by just adjusting the variables file or dropping in a theme. You could also look at using http://www.webjars.org/

edit2:
It may be that wildfly doesn't know how to serve the fonts. I'm not familiar with wildfly (usually use Tomcat) but looking at a [related issue elsewhere](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-252?focusedCommentId=81083&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-81083) it seems you may need:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: see my edit2, having seen your 2nd edit I think this is likely to be the cause.

Comment: thanks. What you suggest in your second edit is not the issue. I added mime-mapping to wildfly configuration before posting anything on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

well - this issue is not resolved - I decided that I don't want to waste time on this crap, and switched to font-awesome. It worked like charm.
thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue following the instructions in this post: http://www.solewing.org/blog/2014/02/bootstrap-glyphicons-and-javaserver-faces-2-x/

The solution is the same as samael's solution, but with slightly different syntax. Alter bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");
  src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix']}") 
           format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") 
           format('woff'), 
       url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}")
           format('truetype'), 
       url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular']}") 
           format('svg');
}
```